# Prove that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive then $\mu$ is a measure.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $S$ be a semiring and let $\mu: S\to [0, \infty]$ be a finite additive measure. Prove that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive then $\mu$ is a measure.

I know the following:

Since $\mu$ is finite additive, we know that $\mu(\emptyset) =0$ and $\displaystyle \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mu(A_i)$ for every disjoint $A_1, A_2 , \dots, A_n \in S$ with $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \in S$.

This is where I am stuck. Can anybody help by pointing me in the right direction as to how I can go about continuing this proof? I know I have not provided much to go by, I am completely new to measure theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:** As pointed out in detail in the comments by [Ramiro](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/190563/ramiro) – as $S$ is a semiring – $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k \in S$ does not ensure that $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}A_k \in S$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the finite additivity of $\mu$ cannot be directly used. One rather has to extend the $S$ to the ring $R(S)$ generated by $S$ and extend $\mu$ on $S$ to the unique extension $\mu '$ on $R(S)$.

Note that finite additivity also holds for $\mu'$ and $\mu'$ coincides with $\mu$ on $S$.

Finally this gives us:

\begin{align*}  \mu\left (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) &\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i)  \tag{ by $\sigma$-subadditivity}  \\  &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n  \mu(A_i) \\&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n  \mu'(A_i) \tag { $\mu'$ and $\mu$ coincides on $S$} \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu'\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right)  \tag { note: $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is in $R(S)$} \\ &\leqslant \mu'\left (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) \tag{ by monotonicity of $\mu'$} \\ &=\mu\left (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) \tag { $\mu'$ and $\mu$ coincides on $S$} \end{align*}

**Original answer:** If we can show that the content $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive, then $\mu$ is a measure on the semiring.

So let $\{A_k\}_{k \geq 1}$ a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $S$, so that $A := \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k \in S$. Then we have

$$\mu(A) \underbrace{\leq}_{\sigma-\text{subadditive}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\mu(A_k)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mu(A_k)}} \underbrace{=}_{\text{finite additivity}} \lim_{n \to \infty}{\underbrace{\mu(\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n}A_k)}_{\leq \mu(A) \text{ because of monotonicity of }\mu}} \leq \mu(A)$$

As we have the same expression on the left and right hand side, all inequalities must already be equalities, which provides us with

$$\mu(A) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\mu(A_k)}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for this

Comment: @user229672 It is necessary to extend the measure to the ring generated by $S$.  Because, since $S$ is a semiring, the fact that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in S$ does NOT ensure that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \in S$ for any $n\geqslant 1$ and so we can not use directly the finite additivity of $\mu$ in $S$.

Comment: @Ramiro I naively transferred this reasoning from when dealing with ring of sets. What would you suggest regarding my answer? Is there a way without needing to extend the measure to the generated ring?

Comment: The simplest path is to extend it to the ring generated by $S$ and remark that the extension is a finitely additive measure (that is all  that is needed).

Comment: Let $\mu'$ be the unique extension to $R(S)$, the ring generated by $S$.  
Then $\mu'$ is also a finite additive measure. Then:

Comment: \begin{align*} 
\mu\left (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) &\leqslant \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_i) = \tag{ by $\sigma$-subadditivity}  \\ 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^n  \mu(A_i)= \\&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{i=1}^n  \mu'(A_i)= \tag { $\mu'$ and $\mu$ coincides on $S$} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu'\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \tag { note: $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is in $R(S)$} \\
&\leqslant \mu'\left (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right)= \tag{ by monotonicity of $\mu'$} \\
&=\mu\left (\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right) \tag { $\mu'$ and $\mu$ coincides on $S$}
\end{align*}

Comment: @johncrab Please, feel free to adjust your answer as I described above.

Comment: Ah, this is great! Just to make sure that I understand correctly (I have not dealt with semirings much): One can say that the extension $R(S)$ is the set of all finite disjoint unions of sets from $S$, right? And $\mu '$ is then defined by $\mu '(C_1 \cup \dots \cup C_n) = \mu(C_1) + \dots  + \mu(C_n)$?

Comment: And a simple example of such a semiring, where my reasoning does not hold, is $\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. Any objections? I'll edit my answer then, thank you very much for the support!

Comment: Right.  Another example where "your reasoning does not hold"  is the semiring of intervals. The union of a countable family of disjoint  intervals may be an interval, while the unions of any finite sub-family fail to be an interval.

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated the answer.